# d3 change attribute of all elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, attributes, selection

I want to change the color of all my svg elements with class "tmp-click" to yellow

```
var yellow = d3.select('svg')
               .selectAll('.tmp-click')
               .attr("fill","yellow);
```

When executing the code only one of the elements is changed, what did I miss?

Comment: You only need `d3.selectAll('.tmp-click').attr("fill","yellow);`. Drop the `select("svg")` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it this way

```
var yellow = d3.selectAll('.tmp-click')
               .style("fill","yellow");
```